# Read a selected a line in and input file

Tags: optimization, file-io, fortran

I have a formatted file, and I would like recursively randomly select one row and read it.
Due to memory issues, it is not possible to read all the data, save it on vectors, and later select one line at time.

I solved in this way (only relevant code is reported), but it is quite slow and I'm wondering if someone could help me to find a fastest way to do it (I'm not fortran expert)

Edit: Yes I would like to use this routine several (~1kk) times, I'm defining the starting parameters for further analysis

```
  PARAMETER(NLINES=10000000)
  REAL ID,E,X,Y,Z,COSX,COSY
  SAVE LOO
  DATA LFIRST / .TRUE. /
  
  IF ( LFIRST ) THEN
  LFIRST = .FALSE.
  OPEN(UNIT=88,FILE="../../../gene_rid.txt",STATUS="OLD")
  END IF

  XI = FLRNDM(XDUMMY)
  LINE = INT(XI * DBLE(NLINES)) + 1

  DO LOO=1,LINE
     READ(88,*,IOSTAT=iostat) ID
  END DO
  READ(88,*,IOSTAT=iostat) ID,E,
 &        COSX, COSY, X, Y, Z
  REWIND(88)
```

This is how the input file is formatted

```
head gene_rid.txt 
  7  0.933549E-03  -.162537E+00  0.136150E-01   -.4791E+01   0.3356E+00   0.2900E+02
  7  0.203748E-02  -.115359E+00  -.217682E+00   -.3453E+01   -.6606E+01   0.2900E+02
  7  0.289498E-02  0.159572E+00  -.954033E-01   0.4767E+01   -.2730E+01   0.2900E+02
```

Comment: If you just want to read one random line from the file I don't see much scope for improvement on the code you already have.  However, if that is a routine you want to use many times, well, that's another matter and you should explain further.

Comment: If all the lines are the same length I would suggest using a direct access file - are they?

Comment: @IanBush yes, I write them in an other script in this format
WRITE(IODRAW,'(i3,3(2x,E12.6),3(3x,E10.4))')

I tried direct access, but I failed

    OPEN(UNIT=88,FILE="../../../ge.txt",STATUS="OLD", RECL=85,                                                                                                                 
    &      ACCESS="DIRECT",FORM='FORMATTED') 
[....]
        READ (88,150,POS=LINE) ID, E, COSX, COSY, X, Y, Z                                                                                                                          
150  format(i3,3(E12.6),3(E10.4))

Comment: Please [edit] that detail into the question, and show what "failed". You may also need to account for the header, so detail on how that is written, and whether you can change the line, would also be valuable.

Comment: It might also be useful to know a bit more about what you're doing with these values once you've read them in. It may be possible to do some caching or something with the data, but we can only guess without more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given it says in the comments that all the lines are the same length I would use a direct access file. Something like the below, take the times with a pinch of salt because who knows what caching the OS is doing.

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat rl.f90
Program testit

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : wp => real64, li => int64

  Implicit None

  Integer, Parameter :: max_file_length =  128
  Integer, Parameter :: max_line_length = 8192
  Integer, Parameter :: n_lines         = 10000000
  Integer, Parameter :: n_tests         = 1000000

  Character( Len = * ), Parameter :: fmt = '( i8, 1x, f14.2 )'
  
  Character( Len = max_file_length ) :: file
  Character( Len = max_line_length ) :: line

  Real( wp ) :: rand
  Real( wp ) :: a

  Integer :: start, finish, rate
  
  Integer :: recl
  Integer :: unit
  Integer :: line_number
  Integer :: d
  Integer :: i

  Logical :: worked

  file = 'test.dat'

  ! Write some test data
  Open( newunit = unit, file = file, form = 'formatted' )
  Call system_clock( start, rate )
  Do  i = 1, n_lines
     Write( unit, fmt ) i, Real( i, wp )
  End Do
  Call system_clock( finish, rate )
  Write( *, * ) 'Write time ', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate 
  Write( *, * ) 'Av. time per write = ', &
       Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate / n_lines
  Close( unit )

  ! Read it via direct access
  ! Work out the record length including the end of record marker
  Write( line, fmt ) 1, 1.0_wp
  recl = Len_trim( line ) + Len( new_line( 'a' ) )
  ! Now read the file
  Open( newunit = unit, file = file, &
       access = 'direct', recl = recl, form = 'formatted' )
  worked = .True.
  Call system_clock( start, rate )
  Do i = 1, n_tests
     Call Random_number( rand )
     line_number = Int( rand * n_lines ) + 1 
     Read( unit, fmt, rec = line_number ) d, a
     If( d /= line_number ) Then
        Write( *, * ) 'Failed to read right line'
        worked = .False.
        Exit
     End If
  End Do
  Call system_clock( finish, rate )
  Close( unit )

  If( worked ) Then
     Write( *, * )
     Write( *, * ) 'Read successful'
     Write( *, * ) 'Read time ', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate 
     Write( *, * ) 'Av. time per read = ', &
          Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate / n_tests
  End If
  
End Program testit
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran -std=f2008 -fcheck=all -Wall -Wextra -g -O rl.f90 
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Write time    8.8620000000000001     
 Av. time per write =    8.8619999999999998E-007

 Read successful
 Read time    2.3670000000000000     
 Av. time per read =    2.3670000000000000E-006
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help to read the file once, and write it to lots of one-line files, e.g.

```
integer, parameter :: nlines = 1e7
character(100) :: line
character(100) :: filename

integer :: i

open(unit=88, file="../../../gene_rid.txt", status="old")
do i=1,nlines
  read(88,'(a)') line
  write(filename,'(a,i0)') "gene_rid", i
  open(unit=89, file=filename, status="new")
  write(89,*) line
  close(89)
enddo
close(88)
```

Then in your main program you only have to open the right one-line file and read one line in each time, rather than scrolling through the entire large file.

If writing `1e7` one-line files is too much for your file system, it might instead be worth writing `1e4` thousand-line files or somesuch.

Comment: I once created a few millions of files on a supercomputer and the admins of the filesystem really did not like me.

Comment: Many small files can easily be the way to kill performance on modern, high performance file systems. And not just for you on a shared machine. But I wouldn't worry @VladimirF, it's the job of sys admins not to like users.

Comment: Leaving aside that this idea is crazee, and that some file systems would just give up on the task, I wonder if the time to find the right file would exceed the time to directly access the right line in the original file anyway.